# Java SQL how to get value from a column?

Tags: java, sql

Nice to meet you all! I wanna get value from a column with the simple following code:

```
String statement = "select rated,vote_count from iptv_media_source where channel_id= '"
                + channelId + "'"; 
float rated = 0; 
int vote_count =0;

try {           
    rs =Main.db.getCon().createStatement().executeQuery(statement);
    rated = rating.getFloat("rated");
    vote_count = rating.getInt("vote_count");       
vote_count++; rated++;

    statement = "UPDATE iptv_media_source SET rated = '"+rated+"' , vote_count = '"+vote_count+"' WHERE channel_id= '" + channelId + "'";
    Main.db.getCon().createStatement().executeUpdate(statement);

} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The UPDATE statement runs well, but these 2 lines:

```
rated = rating.getFloat("rated");
vote_count = rating.getInt("vote_count");
```

got some problems. Thanks for any reply!

Comment: What sort of problems do those 2 lines got? Any error?

Comment: @cherouvim: Most likely compiler errors because `rating` is declared nowhere.

Answer (score 4):

You would first have to move the pointer on the result set to point to the first record returned, before retrieving the column values,by doing like this:

```
rs.next();
```

More [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) about ResultSet

Answer (score 0):

Change these to the following. It may work:

```
rated = rs.getFloat(0);
vote_count = rs.getInt(1);
```

Comment: OHH!!! Thank you so much ! Just this one line and it took me a day. You guys really are my savior.

Comment: I cant see where rating is defined.

Comment: @ziggy i edited my answer.I just saw the questioner question and wrote it.Thanks for finding my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `rs.next()` to progress the cursor, as johnbk said.

Also, change `rating.getFloat` to `rs.getFloat`, as it's the wrong variable.